# Force the number of columns when splitting one column with str.split (panda)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I don't know if the procedure is possible with str.split. But for example, I have the following column in a dataframe df:

```
   Column
0 a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-i-j
1 a-a-b-b-c-c
2 a-a-b-b
```

I know that if I do

```
df['Column'].str.split('-', expand=True)
```

then I will have a result like the following:

```
  0  1  2  3  4      5      6      7      8      9
0 a  b  c  d  e      f      g      h      i      j
1 a  a  b  b  c      c    None   None   None   None
2 a  a  b  b  None  None  None   None   None   None
```

which creates a number of columns depending on the highest number of elements when the splitting is done.

I want to know if is possible to always have 10 columns regardless of the number of elements as long as it is between 0 and 10 and fill the remaining columns with 'None' like here.

So something which would turn the following column:

```
       Column
0 a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h
1 a-a-b-b-c-c
2 a-a-b-b
```

into:

```
  0  1  2  3  4      5      6      7      8      9
0 a  b  c  d  e      f      g      h    None   None
1 a  a  b  b  c      c    None   None   None   None
2 a  a  b  b  None  None  None   None   None   None
```

Comment: You could create a dataframe first with the desired number of columns, and then append the data to it. You should be able to append the str.split

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reindex` afterwards
With improved implementation from  [user3483203](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090026/force-the-number-of-columns-when-splitting-one-column-with-str-split-panda/51090087#comment89168558_51090087)

```
df.Column.str.split('-', expand=True).reindex(columns=range(10))

   0  1  2  3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0  a  b  c  d     e     f     g     h     i     j
1  a  a  b  b     c     c  None  None  None  None
2  a  a  b  b  None  None  None  None  None  None
```

---

A comprehension approach

```
pd.DataFrame([
    (lambda l: l + [None] * (10 - len(l)))(x.split('-'))
    for x in df.Column
], df.index)

   0  1  2  3     4     5     6     7     8     9
0  a  b  c  d     e     f     g     h  None  None
1  a  a  b  b     c     c  None  None  None  None
2  a  a  b  b  None  None  None  None  None  None
```

Comment: Does it create columns with all `None` when we have <10 elements ?

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get that at first.

Comment: Would simply using `df.Column.str.split('-', expand=True).reindex(columns=range(10))` work?

Comment: I have tried both and think `df.Column.str.split('-', expand=True).reindex(columns=range(10))` is indeed more straightforward. I am going to accept this answer as both solutions are working. Thank you both.

Comment: @piRSquared, you caught it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([np.nan]*10).T, pd.DataFrame(df['Column'].str.split('-').tolist())], ignore_index=True).iloc[1:]
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3     4     5     6     7   8   9
1  a  b  c  d     e     f     g     h NaN NaN
2  a  a  b  b     c     c   NaN   NaN NaN NaN
3  a  a  b  b   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN NaN NaN
```